# How to select value based on random selection in jmeter?

Tags: random, parameters, jmeter, selection

We have 2 buttons to decide on yes or no. Here, we have json:

```html
{

"data":{"myquestionlist":

[{"myid":11,"myQuestionId"111,"myselection":[1,0]},
{"myid":12,"myQuestionId":222,"myselection":[0,1]}]
}
}
```

Here, we have another parameter which will decide yes/no. If random selection is first value(from "myselection":[1,0] i.e:1) then the parameter should send "Yes". If my random selection is second value(from "myselection":[0,1] i.e: 1) then parameter will send "No".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're ["overengineering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) things, If you want to send randomly `Yes` or `No` you don't even need to extract these `0` and `1` and convert the number into a word, just send randomly `Yes` or `No` and that would be it.

The easiest option is going for [__chooseRandom() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#chooseRandomsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-0-1-font-sup) available as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle which can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

---

It's also possible using JMeter built-in components:

1. Define 2 JMeter Variables in [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) or using [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

   [image]
2. Use [__RandomFromMultipleVars()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomFromMultipleVars) function where required like:

   ```
   ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(Yes|No,)}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: No, the yes or no is based upon value selected from [1,0]. If my first value is 1 then YES, if value selected is 0 then NO. Inshort, first value is always YES and second value is always NO. Likewise we have [1,0] and [0,1] combination to select for.